# Convert from ListView Adapter to RecyclerView Adapter for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

My project is based on Fragments and I am trying to implement HypeLabs Mesh Network Chat as extra functionality. How do I convert the Activities in the Hype Labs Github Project shown in the attached URL into Fragments such as ChatFragment and ContactsFragment.

The original ContactsViewAdapter is as follows:

```
public class DirectContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
protected final Activity mActivity;
private Map<String, Store> stores;

public DirectContactsAdapter(@NonNull Activity mActivity, Map<String, Store> stores) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
    this.stores = stores;
}

protected Map<String, Store> getStores() {
    return stores;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView;
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.row_direct_contacts, parent, false);
    return new DirectContactsViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(holder instanceof DirectContactsViewHolder) {
        final DirectContactsViewHolder directContactsHolder = (DirectContactsViewHolder) holder;
        final Store contactsStore = this.stores.get(position);
        try {
            directContactsHolder.displayName.setText(contactsStore.getInstance().getRealmStringIdentifier());
            directContactsHolder.contentIndicator.setVisibility(contactsStore.hasNewMessages
                    () ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(DirectContactsFragment.this, DirectChatsFragment
                                    .class);

                            TextView displayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
                            CharSequence charSequence = displayName.getText();

                            setDisplayName(charSequence.toString());

                            Store store = chatApplication.getStores().get(getDisplayName());
                            store.setDelegate(contactActivity);

                            intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_STORE, store.getInstance().getStringIdentifier());

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppHelper.LogCat("Contacts adapters Exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stores.size();
}

public Store getItem(int position) {
    return stores.get(position);
}


public class DirectContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.avatar)
    ImageView userImage;
    @BindView(R.id.display_name)
    TextView displayName;
    @BindView(R.id.new_content)
    ImageView contentIndicator;

    DirectContactsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

}}
```

I am quite new to Fragments and the examples Android Studio generates confuse me further.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: so what is ur problem? What do you want? Your adapter seems to be correct..but u have to put some code in onBindViewHolder method for display something

Comment: Hello @borune thanks for your comment. Yeah the RecyclerViewAdapter seems correct but there are somethings in the ListViewAdapter that have not been implemented, for instance like the onTouch event which opens another Activity passing some data. I also know that I can not use an intent in Fragments, so how do I solve this. So far this is what I have based on some Google research. I have updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

@Victor do u want to pass some data from ur adapter to the Fragment instead of Activity? if so, u should use Callback pattern. For doing that u can create an enclosing interface class as follows:

```
    public class DirectContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private IItemClickListener mListener;
    public void setListener(IItemClickListener listener) {mListener=listener;}

    ...
    public DirectContactsAdapter(@NonNull Activity mActivity, Map<String, Store> stores) { // this is the bad practice to pass Activity object, better pass Context
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.stores = stores;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(holder instanceof DirectContactsViewHolder) {
            final DirectContactsViewHolder directContactsHolder = (DirectContactsViewHolder) holder;
            final Store contactsStore = stores.get(position);
            try {
                directContactsHolder.displayName.setText(contactsStore.getInstance().getRealmStringIdentifier());
                directContactsHolder.contentIndicator.setVisibility(contactsStore.hasNewMessages
                        () ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                TextView displayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_name); // this is redundant cause u use butterknife and ur ViewHolder already have reference to its TextView
                                CharSequence charSequence = displayName.getText(); // u should use DirectContactsViewHolder.displayName.getText() instead

                                setDisplayName(charSequence.toString()); 

                                Store store = chatApplication.getStores().get(getDisplayName());
                                store.setDelegate(contactActivity);

                                if(mListener != null)
                                   mListener.onItemClicked(store.getInstance().getStringIdentifier());
                            }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AppHelper.LogCat("Contacts adapters Exception " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }


    public interface IItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(String identifier); 
    }
```

after doing that u should implement this interface in Fragment:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    DirectContactsAdapter adapter = new DirectContactsAdapter(...);
    adapter.setListener(new DirectContactsAdapter.IItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        void onItemClicked(String identifier) {
            //do what u want with identifier
    });
}
```